# Using Templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a homework that asks me to do the following:

> Design a template class named FlexArray which offers flexible array
>   indexes.  The user of the class can set the lower index and upper
>   index when the object is declared.
>
> Examples of user code:
>
> FlexArray  a (1,5);              // lower index is 1 and the upper index is
>   5 FlexArray b(-5, 10);        // lower index is -5 and the upper
>   index is 10
>
> Provide the following functions for your class:
>
> 1. default constructor
> 2. parameterized constructor in which the user specified lower index and upper index
> 3. destructor
> 4. copy constructor
> 5. assignment operator
> 6. overloaded [ ] operator with similar semantics to [ ] already used with built-in arrays.
>
> Errors on PRE conditions may be handled with assert statements or
>   try/catch blocks.  There is no resizing of the array offered. 
>   Subscripts must be in range.

The book is really no help for creating templates. I was hoping for someone to provide me with some direction on this problem and to see if my code is on the right track. I've tried to start this problem by the very limited scope of the book and different resources online and got:

```
#ifndef H_templates
#define H_templates

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>           
class FlexArray
{  public:                  
    FlexArray();            // POST: empty FlexArray
    FlexArray(LI,UI);               // POST: Parameterized Constructor
    ~FlexArray();           // POST: destructor
    CopyArr(Array* sourceArray, Array* destinationArray, size);             // POST: Copies array

    //Overloading the assignment operators to add arrays(?) Unsure if
    // this is what is meant by the original question
    FlexArray operator+
      (const FlexArray& otherFlexArray) const;
      //Overload the operator +
    FlexArray operator-
      (const FlexArray& otherFlexArray) const;
      //Overload the operator -
    FlexArray operator[]
      (const FlexArray& otherFlexArray) const;
      //Overload the operator []

private:
    T FlexArray[size];      // Flex array   
    int size;               // number of items Array
    int LI;                 //Lower Index
    int UI;                 //Upper Index
};

template <typename T>  
FlexArray<T>::FlexArray ()  
// POST: empty FlexArray
{    size = 0;  }

template <typename T>  
FlexArray<T>::~FlexArray()  
// POST: destructor
{    }
template <typename T>  
FlexArray<T>::CopyArr( Array* sourceArray, Array* destinationArray, size)   
//Pre: Takes 3 arguments, the original array, the array to copy too, and, the size of array
// POST: Copies the array
{   
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        sourceArray[i] = destinationArray[i]
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Assignment operator is `operator=`.

Comment: +1 for stating homework!

Comment: A template in C++ is a family of objects - with the same features but hosting different object. For example use templates for stacks, queues, lists. NOT FOR THINGS THAT HAVE 'IS A RELATIONSHIP TO; (like shapes/rectangles/square/circles....)

Comment: +1 for attempting the question yourself before asking!

Comment: If you get homework like this in class, I'm jealous. I only ever get boring homework. :(

Comment: Agreed. Everybody bookmark this as an example of a well-asked homework problem.

Comment: A postcondition is not the same as a one-line description of the function.

Comment: When I teach templates to my students, I often advise them to start by coding a non-template working solution, and only then transform the implementation into a template. In your case, I would recommend that you start by writing a class `IntFlexArray` (containing integers), and only when this class work correctly can you proceed to making it a class template. This way, you limit the number of errors you can make. First focus on making constructors and destructors work correctly, then try to overload the needed operators, then generalize your class so that it works with any type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're off to a good start.  A couple of things to point out.

The assignment asks for a default constructor, BUT also states that resizing the array is not supported.  These two requirements logically conflict -- your assumption (to use `size=0`) seems logical, but then this default constructed object will always be empty.  Not a huge problem, just a logical disconnect in the requirements.

A paramaterized constructor taking the upper and lower bounds.  You've started on this as:

```
FlexArray(LI,UI);               // POST: Parameterized Constructor
```

However, `LI` and `UI` will need types.  Since you have to support negative indices, this should be a signed type, like `int`.

A copy-constructor, is a constructor that takes an object of the same type.  You have not declared one of these.  It should have the form:

```
FlexArray(const FlexArray&);
```

The assignment operator is the `=` operator that allows you to do this:

```
FlexArray a, b;
b = a;
```

You haven't declared one of these.  It should take the form:

```
FlexArray& operator=(const FlexArray&);
```

The implementation will be similar to the copy-constructor (in fact, the copy-constructor could simply be implemented in terms of the assignment operator).

An overloaded `[]` operator.  You have declared one of these, but it's not really in the correct form -- doesn't take the appropriate argument types.  The usage will look like this:

```
FlexArray arr(-5, 10);

// This is a call to operator[]
arr[3] = value;
```

Given that, try to think about what argument type it should take.

Now, on to the functional requirements.  Given an upper and lower bound, you have to create an array that can be indexed using those boundaries.  Think about what you need to know in order to do that.  I will suggest that you need to know the difference of the upper and lower bound (this will be the SIZE of your array).  You should check in the constructor that the upper bound is greater than the lower bound, or you cannot effectively create this array.

Now, to actually build your array of objects, you will need to dynamically allocate some memory for them.  You have a try at this with:

```
T FlexArray[size];      // Flex array
```

But this has some problems.  First off, I don't think you can name it `FlexArray` as this will collide with the name of your class.  Secondly, this requires that `size` is a compile time constant, which runs afoul of our requirements.  So, you will need to dynamically allocate the internal array of `T` objects (using `new` if you haven't learned about smart pointers yet).  Remember to deallocate this array of objects in your destructor.

Now functionally, how will the `[]` work?  Requirement is to do bounds checking, so given an index you have to know if it is too low (outside the lower bound) or too high (outside the upper bound) and raise an appropriate error.  Now you have a dynamically allocated (0-based) array of `T` objects -- given an index that is user specified you need to find the appropriate object to return.  Think about how to make that happen.

Also, you've declared `+` and `-` operators, though the requirement does not specify those should be there.  I would suggest taking them out.  The `+` operator implies that the array will be resized (which is contradicted by the requirements), and the `-` is ambiguous, what does it mean to subtract two arrays?  Both of these functions could be valid, but for this assignment are unnecessary.

No more hints :)

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. For the copy-constructor, where/how do I actually write the copy part for a template? I know in previous hw's when we overloaded something we wrote the function in its own .cpp file but it seems that many items related to templates are kept in the header file or it may not even matter. So like: `FlexArray<T>::operator=(const FlexArray&) const{
   //a forloop to copy code?
   }`

Comment: Yes, templates have all the code in the header file (generally), and you've got the basic syntax correct.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I think i've got a handle on it now!

Comment: Glad to help.  That's what we're here for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing I notice off the bat is that you don't really have a copy constructor. If you were thinking `CopyArr` qualifies, it does not. The syntax should be in your class materials, but it is basically a constructor that takes in a `const` reference to the class as its only parameter.

You also don't have an assignment operator (aka: copy assignment). Again, the exact syntax should be in your class materials, but the routine name would be `operator=`.

Also, your array operator doesn't to me appear to have "similar semantics to [ ] already used with built-in arrays." A built-in array returns the element type (which would be `T` in your case, no?), but yours is returning the entire `FlexArray` type.

As for template development itself, here's what I suggest if you are having trouble. Start by developing the whole thing to work as a simple (non-template) class with one simple type (eg: `int`). Get it tested and verified to work that way. *Then* transform it into a template. Tracking down errors within templates can be a challenge even for experienced developers.

Comment: A copy constructor is *not* just overloading the `=` operator.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor.  It's a real constructor.  It is called implicitly when you assign an instance of the object (note: not just a pointer but the object itself) or when you pass an instance of the object into a method.

Comment: Oh, I tried to write a copy function vs overloading the `=` operator

Comment: @JackEdmonds - Sorry. That was a breif brain-fart. Fixed before I even saw your comment. Definitely worthy of the -1 while it was there though. C++ is tough enough to learn without confusing the poor OQ with the wrong terminology.

Comment: @T.E.D. That's fine.  I just wanted to make it clear as the copy constructor can be quite confusing.  Also I was not the one who gave you the -1.

Comment: @JackEdmonds - Whoever did, if that's what it was for I entirely understand. I try to get my answer's general gist down fast, then make lots of edits to clean up the details. It leaves me rather succeptible to this if I scew something up on an early iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers haven't gone into this, there are a few odd things about:

```
template <typename T>  
FlexArray<T>::CopyArr( Array* sourceArray, Array* destinationArray, size)   
//Pre: Takes 3 arguments, the original array, the array to copy too, and, the size of array
// POST: Copies the array
{    
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        sourceArray[i] = destinationArray[i]
    }
}
```

The `size` parameter would need a type as well as a name.

You've made it a member function of an object, and yet it doesn't operate on that object at all. It only operates on the objects passed in the parameters. You could instead make that function accept one array (the one to copy from). Call it `assign`. You can then use it to implement your `copy constructor` and `operator=`.

The other oddity is the type `Array`. Where is that defined?

Comment: Whoops :) it isn't defined anywhere. I was looking at an example in the book, could I just use `CopyArr(sourceArray[], destinationArray[], size)`?

Comment: What compiler are you running your code through as you write it? (This is a loaded question!)

Comment: When declaring a function you need to say what the return type is (or put `void` to return nothing), and you need to state the type of each parameter before you give the name. `int add(int first, int second) { return first + second; }`

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I need to get better with syntax. For an array type, `int` is alright because it is just holding addresses not really complex numbers. - Is my logic right?

Comment: Yes, I think this was supposed to be his "copy constructor". I pointed out that it wasn't. IMHO a complete rewrite will be nessecary once he sees the syntax of a real copy constructor, so it didn't bear pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You want dynamic allocation. The simplest way to do this is to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: We just went over using vectors in class the other day, So I know its relevant to the homework. Could you expand your answer a little bit.

Comment: This is a good point, but it's possible the intention of the question is for you to allocate the storage with `new` and `delete` as there would be no reason to write your own copy constructor, destructor, etc. if you use `std::vector` for your storage. The defaults would take care of everything for you.

Comment: Not so sure, since this was homework. It would be quite possible to do it with an array and throw an exception if the user asks for bounds too far apart. But if @Nick's teacher just introduced vectors, it might behoove him to go ask the teacher for a hint if he should be using one here...